# How do I get a file from a different project but same solution?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have the following setup:

SolutionProjects containing Project1, Project2.

Project1 contains code, Project2 contains a folder called Images and in it is a file 'example.png'.

Now I want to use 'example.png' in Project1, e.g. `<img src="example.png"/>`

I can't navigate there via `../../` because it stops at the root of Project1 and doesn't let me go up by one into the solution folder.

I want to use relative paths if possible.

Can someone with more experience help me out?

Comment: I tried to drag a file from another project into a razor file of another project, the output was an absolute path. What you could do is use an image container/storage online that contains images from both projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two web projects, they can be deployed in different applications within the same website, different web sites on the same server or even different websites on different servers.

You cannot navigate towards the other project using `../`, because the file structure you have on disk in your solution does not necessarily match the file structure after deploying. Your web application is not going to serve another web application's files.

In other words, the file may not be where you expect it to, and you cannot go up beyond your wwwroot.

You'll have to prefix the actual site that the other project is going to use. During development this may be `https://localhost:12345/`, and it'd be wise to make this configurable.

So your image tag becomes something like `<img src="@(Html.ImageServerUrl)/Images/Foo.png" />`.